# Combining Google Play Game and Google App Engine access in an Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-games

I have used Google play games to create an Android game with achievements, leaderboard, and realtime multiplayer play.

I now would like to include some server related stuff, planning on using google app engine. My understanding is that a Google Play Game backend instance is built atop an app engine instance? How would I combine using the google game play API (extending BaseGameActivity for its login management and have access to achievements, etc) and still use the google app engine for other services exposed via servlets?

My main concern would presumably be sharing the authentication- I could envision simply making a separate Game play server and a separate app engine server, but then the user would somehow have to log in to each separately, right, being rather annoying.

I have tried to search for how to do this, expecting it may be fairly common, but have turned up only a few references that are not exactly what I need, talking obliquely about Auth tokens and such. If those are actually what I need, I may need a step by step guide as to how to take the info from the google play game APIs, and how to send it to the app engine server calls appropriately, so the user only sees the single "google play game" login.

Thank you

Rob

Comment: Wish it has some answers...

Comment: Me too. I have the app I'm working on currently with the server as a single instance (the google game play AND App engine are the same server), but since I haven't worked out how to share the authentication... there is none for the app engine at the moment. I'd like to put some in before releasing the app.. at least to avoid DOS-type attacks, or trying to roll my own "application" secured calls.